# Integral remainder converges to 0

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I want to show that

$\displaystyle \log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$

for $-1<x\leq1$

i want to show it with the integral remainder of the taylor series that gave me:

$R_{n+1}(x)=\int_{x_0}^{x} (x-t)^n \frac{1}{(1+t)^{n+1}} dt$

now i want to show that it converges to 0 but everything i did ended in divergence.

any hints are welcome.

Comment: What is the $x_0$?

Comment: $x_0$ should be equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

A [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402947/taylor-expansion-of-1x-to-binomial-series-why-does-the-remainder-term-c/402997#402997). Here is a reference for the [remainder theorem](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jmr/141/remainder.pdf). Since you are deriving the Taylor series at $0$, then $x_0=0$. Now,

$$ |R_{n+1}(x)|\leq \int_{0}^{x} (x-t)^n \frac{1}{(1+t)^{n+1}} dt \leq \int_{0}^{x} x^n \frac{1}{(1+t)^{n+1}} dt < \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+t)^{n+1}} dt $$

$$ = \frac{1-2^{-n}}{n} \longrightarrow_{n\to \infty} 0 $$

Note that, we used the inequality $ x-t \leq x $ which follows from the fact

$$ 0\leq t \leq x \implies -x \leq -t \leq 0 \implies 0<x-t < x. $$