# Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^α$ to binomial series – why does the remainder term converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

For $α ∈ ℝ$ the function $g_α \colon B_1(0) → ℝ, x ↦ (1+x)^α$ is $C^∞$ and $g_α^{(n)}(x) = n! \tbinom{α}{n}(1+x)^{α-n}$, where $\tbinom{α}{n} = \frac{α(α-1)\cdots(α-n+1)}{n!}$ is the generalized binomial coefficient.
I want to show that $g_α$ has a Taylor expansion $g_α (x) = \sum_{k=0}^∞ \tbinom{α}{k}x^k$. I can easily show that the series really converges for $|x| < 1$, but can I use this fact to show that the remainder term
$$R_n(x) = \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^n}{n!} (n+1)! \tbinom{α}{n+1}(1+t)^{α-n-1} dt$$
or in Lagrange form
$$\quad R_n(x) = \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} (n+1)! \binom{α}{n+1}(1+ξ)^{α-n-1} = x^{n+1} \binom{α}{n+1}(1+ξ)^{α-n-1}$$
converges to zero for $|x| < 1$?

How else can I show that the remainder term converges to zero for $|x| < 1$?

---

**Progress**: Using the Lagrange form, for $x ∈ (-1,1)$ and $n ∈ ℕ$ there is an $h=h(n,x) ∈ (0,1)$ such that:

$$|R_n(x)| = \Big| x^{n+1} \binom{α}{n+1}(1+hx)^{α-n-1} \Big| = \Big| \binom{α}{n+1}\big(\frac{x}{1+hx}\big)^{n+1}(1+ξ)^{α} \Big| $$
If $x > 0$, then $\big|\frac{x}{1+hx}\big| < {\big|\frac{x}{1+x}\big|}< 1$ and so for $q := \big|\frac{x}{1+x}\big|$, since $\sum_{k=0}^∞ \tbinom{α}{n} q^n$ converges:
$$|R_n(x)| ≤ \Big| \binom{α}{n+1} · q^{n+1} ·(1+ξ)^{α} \Big| \overset{n → ∞}{\longrightarrow} 0$$
The problem is still open for $x < 0$.
Mhenni suggested to use Stirling approximation, but I want to do this more elementary and I think it is possible.

Comment: You can follow the technique done in this [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379145/integral-remainder-converges-to-0).

Comment: Should it be $\big|\frac{x}{1+hx}\big| < {\big|\frac{x}{1}\big|}< 1$ for $x>0$?

Comment: I apologize for commenting on such an old post. Could you clarify why $\sum_{k=0}^∞ \tbinom{α}{n} q^n$ is known to converge and what it converges to? I couldn’t figure it out for myself.

Comment: @DavidChoi I don’t know what it converges to, but the quotients of the general term converge in absolute values to $q < 1$, so the general term converges to zero, which is all that is needed. I don’t know what my thinking was eight years ago in justifying this by the convergences of the series. But have a look at my own answer, there it is argued in more detail and, I hope, correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, I think that I got it. One needs to proceed differently:

Let $x ∈ ℝ$ such that $|x| < 1$.
For $t ∈ ℝ$ between $x$ and zero, one has $0 ≤ |t| ≤ |x| < 1$ as well as $|x-t| < |1+t|$, because:

- for $x > 0$ one has $|x-t| = x - t < 1 < 1 + t = |1 + t|$, and
- for $x < 0$ one has $|x-t| = t - x < t + 1 = |1 + t|$, since $-x < 1$.

Therefore $\big|\frac{x-t}{1+t}\big|$ assumes a maximum $q<1$ for $t$ on the compact interval between zero and $x$.
Then:
\begin{align*}
 |R_n(x)| &= \Big| \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^n}{n!} g_α^{(n+1)}(t) dt \Big|\\
 &≤ \Bigg| \int_0^x \Big| \frac{(x-t)^n}{n!} g_α^{(n+1)}(t) \Big| dt \Bigg| \\
 &\overset{(1)}{=} \Bigg| \int_0^x \Big| \frac{(x-t)^n}{(1+t)^n} ·(α-n) · \binom{α}{n} · (1+t)^{α-1} \Big| dt \Bigg|\\
 &\overset{(2)}{≤} n · \binom{α}{n} ·|q|^n · \Bigg| \int_0^x |α/n -1| ·|1+t|^{α-1} dt\Bigg| \\
 &\overset{(3)}{≤} n · \binom{α}{n} · |q|^n · (|α| +1) · C \overset{n → ∞}{\longrightarrow} 0,
\end{align*}
where the convergence follows from $|(n+1)\tbinom{α}{n+1}\big/n\tbinom{α}{n}|\overset{n → ∞}{\longrightarrow} 1$ and $|q| < 1$, and

- (1) $g_α^{(n)}(t) = (n+1)! \tbinom{α}{n+1}(1+t)^{α-n-1}$ and $\tbinom{α}{n+1} = \tfrac{α-n}{n+1} \tbinom{α}{n}$,
- (2) $\big|\frac{x-t}{1+t}\big|^n ≤ |q|^n$, and
- (3) $|α/n - 1| ≤ |α| + 1$, and $C := \Big| \int_0^x |1+t|^{α-1} dt\Big|$

Comment: You should separate the cases $0\leq t\leq x<1$ and $-1<x\leq t\leq 0$ becasue the inequality is not true for all $0\leq |t|\leq |x|<1$. It really takes $x,t$ of the same sign.

Comment: Other than that, it looks good. A nice illustration of the advantage of the integral remainder over the Lagrange remainder.

Comment: @julien Yes, right. But in the integral, $t$ has the same sign as $x$, I was silently assuming this. Thanks for taking a look at it!

Comment: Might be even easier to start from $R_n(x) =  \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^n}{n!} g_α^{(n+1)}(t) dt=\frac{(x-ξ)^n}{n!} g_α^{(n+1)}(ξ)x$ without even bothering integral remainder.

Comment: @Nicholas Okay, yes. It seems like you don’t need the integral remainder, but I find it more illustrative since the crucial point is that the integrand attains a maximum less than one on the integral interval. This point is way less prominent if you hide the integrand and the compact interval it lives on within some anonymous $ξ$. But yeah, the integral looks a bit more clunky.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z)=(1+z)^\alpha$ and $g(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{\alpha}{n}z^n$.

If $\alpha$ is a nonnegative integer, it is clear that both functions coincide on $\mathbb{C}$ by the binomial theorem. So we assume that $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{N}$ from now on, so that $\binom{\alpha}{n}\neq 0$ for every $n\geq 0$.

Using the principal branch of the complex logarithm, we see that $g(z)=\exp(\alpha\log(1+z))$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,-1]$, whence on the open unit disk $D$ in particular.

Now observe that 
$$
\frac{\Big|\binom{\alpha}{n+1}\Big||z|^{n+1}}{\Big|\binom{\alpha}{n}\Big||z|^{n}}=\frac{|\alpha-n||z|}{n+1}\longrightarrow |z|.
$$
So the radius of convergence of $g$ is $1$ by the ratio test. Hence $g$ converges to a holomorphic function on $D$.

For every $x>0$, the remainder in the approximation of $f$ by its degree $n$ Taylor polynomial at $0$ is, by Taylor-Lagrange,
$$
R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}=\binom{\alpha}{n+1}(1+c)^{\alpha-n-1}x^{n+1}=(1+c)^\alpha\binom{\alpha}{n+1}\left(\frac{x}{1+c} \right)^{n+1}
$$
for some $0<c<x$. Since $0<\frac{x}{1+c}<1$, the convergence of $g$ at $\frac{x}{1+c}$ implies that the rhs above tends to $0$, since it is a constant times its general term. So the remainder of the Taylor approximation tends to $0$.

It follows that $f$ and $g$ coincide on $(0,1)$.

By the isolated zero principle, $f$ and $g$ coincide on the whole open unit disk $D$.

Comment: Okay, but from the convergence of the Taylor series of $(1+x)^α$, how can you conclude that it is represented by its Taylor series?

Comment: @K.Stm. Here is something better than my previous silly post. If you allow complex analysis.

Comment: Thanks! What is the isolated zero princple, though? Also, I found a solution using only elementary real analysis.

Comment: @K.Stm. If $f$ is holomorphic on an open connected set $\Omega$ and if there is a point $z_0\in\Omega$ which is a limit point of zeros of $f$, then $f$ is equal to $0$ on $\Omega$.

Comment: Ah, it’s what I know as the *identity theorem*! Could’ve guessed that from the name.

Comment: @K.Stm. It is much stronger than the identity theorem I know, which assumes that $f$ vanishes on an open subset of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Following the technique in the [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379145/integral-remainder-converges-to-0). Let $ g(n,\alpha)= \frac{(n+1)!}{n!} \tbinom{α}{n+1}$, for not to have a mess

$$ \Big|R_n(x)\Big| \leq g(n,\alpha)\int_0^x {(x-t)^n} (1+t)^{α-n-1} dt$$

$$ \leq g(n,\alpha)x^n\int_0^x (1+t)^{α-n-1} dt $$

$$ < g(n,\alpha)\int_0^1 (1+t)^{α-n-1} dt,\quad \mathrm{since}\quad |x|<1,\, \int_{0}^{x}\leq \int_{0}^{1}. $$

$$\implies \Big|R_n(x)\Big| < g(n,\alpha)\frac{2^{\alpha-n}-1}{\alpha-n}$$

> $$  \Big|R_n(x)\Big| = \frac{\alpha!(2^{\alpha-n}-1)}{(\alpha-n)!n!}. $$

Now, you can see that the remainder goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$ with some restrictions on $\alpha$. Try to use [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $n! \sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2 \pi n}$ and see what you get.

**Note:**

1) we used the inequality $ x-t \leq x $ which follows from

$$ 0\leq t \leq x \implies -x \leq -t \leq 0 \implies 0<x-t < x. $$

2)

> $$ \tbinom{α}{n}(2^{α-n} - 1)= \frac{\alpha!(2^{\alpha-n}-1)}{(\alpha-n)!n!}. $$

Comment: Can you explain why the last term converges to zero? (By the way, I read it as $\tbinom{α}{n}(2^{α-n} - 1)$. Many thanks, so far.) As $2^{α-n} - 1$ converges to $-1$, $\tbinom{α}{n}$ should be converging to zero, right?

Comment: @K.Stm.: It is just taking the limit as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: I’m unsure, does this also work for the general binomial coefficient? I don’t see it.

Comment: @K.Stm.: Where is the problem?

Comment: For $α = -1$, don’t you have $\tbinom{α}{n} = \tfrac{(-1)·(-1-1)·(-1-2) \cdots (-1-n+1)}{n!} = \tfrac{-n!}{n!} = -1$ constantly?

Comment: @K.Stm.: What you said in your first comment is correct.

Comment: @K.Stm.: Ok, I see what you mean.

Comment: @K.Stm.: What do you think this  $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\alpha!}{n!(\alpha-n)!} $ equals to?

Comment: I think it is ill-defined if you don’t use the gamma function to make sense of the factorials. But I don’t know what happens for $\tbinom{α}{n} \overset{n → ∞}{\longrightarrow} ?$

Comment: @K.Stm.: I added more material which helps you to find the limit.